# ConvNet validation accuracy relation with each epoch

Tags: validation, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, epoch

When training a CNN, why can the validation loss improve in an epoch even if an epoch before it the validation loss has not improved? I don't use any dropout and the training and validation dataset remain the same after each epoch

Model:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', 
                        input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
#model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Example below: epoch 14 improves val_loss while epoch 13 did not. How can that be? What is the intuition behind this?

```python
Epoch 12/20
Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve
14s - loss: 1.1619 - acc: 0.6079 - val_loss: 1.2863 - val_acc: 0.5308
Epoch 13/20
Epoch 00012: val_loss did not improve
14s - loss: 1.1741 - acc: 0.6029 - val_loss: 1.3020 - val_acc: 0.5930
Epoch 14/20
Epoch 00013: val_loss improved from 1.11924 to 0.97569, saving model to model.weights.best.hdf5
14s - loss: 1.1895 - acc: 0.6005 - val_loss: 0.9757 - val_acc: 0.6614
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you'd expect the trend to be one of improvement, then stabilization, possibly ultimately followed by deterioration as overfitting sets in. However, the validation accuracy is a noisy process. You are not training directly on it, so it's possible for it to go up or down a bit.

One way to think of this is to note that any deep network describes a complicated, highly nonlinear function, parameterized by a large number of variables. At each step, the training algorithm tries to nudge these parameters so that your nonlinear function has the desired values at the points given by the training examples. But the validation accuracy measures this alignment on a different set of examples. It's certainly possible that at some stages in this training process, an improvement in the accuracy on the training set will result in a deterioration in the validation set, purely by chance - and that this will get fixed in a later iteration.

Moreover, even the training accuracy can fluctuate, because you generally train on a minibatch, rather than training on the entire training set at once. So, it's possible for a particular minibatch to contain a bunch of examples which nudge the function in a particular direction that happens to be harmful to the majority of other training examples. This typically gets fixed by subsequent minibatches, but can and will cause the training accuracy to go down a bit from time to time.